# Class to textfile to list

Tags: python, class, pickle, file-handling

I am currently working on a project trying to make a simple bank system.
The basics of the system is done as far as im concerned but there is one problem. I am trying to make a file saving system for my "bank accounts". When a new account is created (aka, a new class is made) it's supposed to be saved in a textfile so that next time you open the program, that bank account(class) should already be loaded and avaliable. This is intented to be used for sever accounts.

The problem I run into is not saving the class to a text file, but loading it up into my list where I keep all my classes that are made. So somehow I need to be able to load in all classes from my textfile to the list everytime the program starts up. Tried using pickle but with my lack of knowledge it just made my program crash. Anyone who could help?

How it looks when I create a class and try to save it to a list
(Python)

```
def nyttkonto():
global konton, aktiv
persnr = simpledialog.askinteger("Personnummer","Ange personnummer (8 siffor)")
fnamn = simpledialog.askstring("Förnamn", "Ange förnamn").lower().capitalize()
enamn = simpledialog.askstring("Efternamn", "Ange efternamn").lower().capitalize()
money = simpledialog.askinteger("Startkapital","Ange startkapitalet på det nya konto")
konton.append(KontoAnvandare(persnr, fnamn, enamn, money))
#This is where the problem starts
with open("kontolista.txt","r") as k:
    folder = k.read()
    konton.append(folder)
#This is where the problem ends, sort of
aktiv = len(konton)-1
visaKonto()
```

the list "konton" is set to konton = [] as a part of the code, so I need to be able to fill it upon restart.

Comment: Show us your whole code, including how the `bankaccounts.txt` file is created, and the complete error message.

Comment: Perhaps using `pickle.dump` and `pickle.load`?

Comment: Should `bank_account.append` be `bank_accounts.append`?

Comment: In that example yeah, but in I update the code and removed my example. This is what the entire Def looks like

Answer (score 0):

Your `bank_accounts.append(load)` is not indented to be a part of `with`.

Comment: I don't have it in the same part, but it still gives me the 0 objects error

Comment: It should be in the same part. But how are you saving them?

Comment: Updated it, the code I posted is my Def for making a bank account looks like, and in the near bottom is how I try to append it

Comment: The input comments basically just say that you should enter first name, last name, personal number and starting value and then it saves those values to the class. The list that I am trying to save it to is called "konton"

Answer (score 0):

Do it using pickle!

```
import pickle

# create bank_accounts.txt
pickle.dump([], "bank_accounts.txt") # do this once than remove from your code

# load bank accounts
bank_accounts = pickle.load("bank_accounts.txt")

# add new accounts
bank_accounts.append(new_account)
bank_accounts.append(other_account)

# save bank accounts
pickle.dump(bank_accounts, "bank_accounts.txt")
```

Comment: Does this really solve the problem with the "konton = [ ]"? My program is kind of based around the classes being placed into this list. Do I use "konton.append(bank_accounts)" after loading it?

Comment: `pickle.load` will load `konton` and all the classes inside it. Yes you can use `konton.append(bank_accounts)`.